# mismatch unicode character between pandas dataframe and csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, utf-8

l have a class of character saved in a csv file.
when l print it in my python terminal using this command :

```
df_classes = pd.DataFrame({'classes':classes})
```

l get the following :

```
Â    [Â]
Æ    [Æ]
Ç    [Ç]
È    [È]
É    [É]
Ê    [Ê]
Ë    [Ë]
Î    [Î]
Ï    [Ï]
Ô    [Ô]
Û    [Û]
Ü    [Ü]
à    [à]
â    [â]
æ    [æ]
ç    [ç]
è    [è]
é    [é]
ê    [ê]
ë    [ë]
î    [î]
ï    [ï]
ô    [ô]
ù    [ù]
û    [û]
ü    [ü]
ÿ    [ÿ]
```

However when l put them in csv file and open a csv file

```
with open('classes.csv', 'a') as f:
    df_classes.to_csv(f, header=False)


Ã‚  ['\xc3\x82']
Ã†  ['\xc3\x86']
Ã‡  ['\xc3\x87']
Ãˆ  ['\xc3\x88']
Ã‰  ['\xc3\x89']
ÃŠ  ['\xc3\x8a']
Ã‹  ['\xc3\x8b']
ÃŽ  ['\xc3\x8e']
Ã  ['\xc3\x8f']
Ã”  ['\xc3\x94']
Ã›  ['\xc3\x9b']
Ãœ  ['\xc3\x9c']
Ã   ['\xc3\xa0']
Ã¢  ['\xc3\xa2']
Ã¦  ['\xc3\xa6']
Ã§  ['\xc3\xa7']
Ã¨  ['\xc3\xa8']
Ã©  ['\xc3\xa9']
Ãª  ['\xc3\xaa']
Ã«  ['\xc3\xab']
Ã®  ['\xc3\xae']
Ã¯  ['\xc3\xaf']
Ã´  ['\xc3\xb4']
Ã¹  ['\xc3\xb9']
Ã»  ['\xc3\xbb']
Ã¼  ['\xc3\xbc']
Ã¿  ['\xc3\xbf']
```

How can l get the same characters as those in `df_class`

```
**EDIT1**
```

If l store them in a `hdf5` file rather rath `csv`  file it works properly

```
df_classes.to_hdf("classes.h5",'table')
```

what's wrong with csv ?

Comment: It seems that your data gets saved as UTF-8 correctly in the TSV. But when you load that data again (you don't show how you do that), apparently the data is interpreted is loaded as bare strings (if this is Python 2) or with Latin-1 encoding (if this is Python 3).

Comment: please see my update.

Comment: How do you get the data from file in the second case?

Comment: when l open my csv file (not in python or terminal) with libreoffice Calc or Excel

Comment: Ok, I see now. Then Calc or Excel are using the wrong encoding (Latin-1 instead of UTF-8) when opening the file. The file is fine, but the interpretation by Calc/Excel is wrong. For the second column, I'm not sure what you want to have there, but it looks like the Python 2 `repr` of a list with one encoded `str` element. But that's not an encoding issue.

Comment: What's wrong so ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the second column, I think: it reflects the data you have there (lists with a single byte string each). If the default pandas csv dump doesn't look the way you want it to, then you probably have to format the data yourself.